# EnhanceIO: Write-through vs Read-only

Tags: cache, flashcache, enhanceio

I have installed an [EnhanceIO](https://github.com/stec-inc/EnhanceIO) SSD cache on my notebook.

> EnhanceIO supports three caching modes: read-only, write-through, and
>     write-back.
>
> Read-only caching mode causes EnhanceIO to direct write IO requests
>   only  to HDD. Read IO requests are issued to HDD and the data read
>   from HDD is   stored on SSD. Subsequent Read requests for the same
>   blocks are carried    out from SSD, thus reducing their latency by a
>   substantial amount.
>
> In Write-through mode - reads are handled similar to Read-only mode.
>     Write-through mode causes EnhanceIO to write application data to both
>     HDD and SSD. Subsequent reads of the same data benefit because they
>   can   be served from SSD.
>
> Write-back improves write latency by writing application requested
>   data  only to SSD. This data, referred to as dirty data, is copied
>   later to  HDD asynchronously. Reads are handled similar to Read-only
>   and   Write-through modes.

My cache has default type of Write-Through. I am thinking that Read-Only mode should be almost the same fast and would save my SSD from degrading, because of avoiding unnecessary writes to it.

Am I correct?